# Error Missing Class en layout de mi activity

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, layout

No sé qué ha pasado hoy que he creado una Acitivy normalmente, como siempre hago. Abro el layout y está la pantalla gris marcando un error en el que dice: Missing Clases.

Cada vez que creo una nueva Activity, la clase me marca muchos errores en rojo y al layout le pasa lo ya comentado, pero sin embargo en las clases ya creadas no me da ningín tipo de error.

Me he percatado también de que en el gradle, la línea implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' está marcada en rojo y no me dice por qué se produce este error. Me acaba de pasar esto y no tengo ni idea de por qué me da este error así de golpe. ¿Cómo se solucionaría?

[image: Missing Class]

[image: Dependencias]

Gracias.

Comment: Es en el proyecto de Kotlin con el que actualmente estas trabajando ?

Comment: Sí, el mismo proyecto con el que he preguntado más de una duda por aquí. Hoy de golpe me ha pasado eso. He mirado un apartado y me recomienda pasarme a AndroidX en lugar de usar appcompat, pero me da miedo hacer el cambio y que empiecen a salir errores.

Answer (score 0):

Mencionas que en tu archivo `build.gradle` tienes problemas en la dependencia:

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

pero en tu proyecto incluso usas Kotlin, me parece raro que aún estés usando bibliotecas de soporte, lo ideal es cambiar a AndroidX, puedes migrar tu proyecto completamente de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Al realizar la conversión a AndroidX obtienes el error:

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> - android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout( Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path, Edit XML , Create
>   Class)

el cual indica que estas usando una biblioteca de soporte para `ConstraintLayout` (`android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`)

dentro de tu `build.gradle` cambia la dependnecia por:

```
dependencies {
   ... 
   ...
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'

}
```

Comment: Hola. Acabo de hacerlo y me sigue dando errores al crear una Activity nueva. Es más, si entro en gradle.properties me salen errores por todas partes también. En el layout me sigue apareciendo el Missing Class. Voy a subir una captura con el error y edito la descripción de la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que por algún motivo, android studio me está utilizando support en lugar de AndroidX cada vez que creo una Activity, porque en las otras Activity que creé antes sí está usando AndroidX, pero ayer de golpe y porrazo, al crear una activity nueva, usa support en lugar de AndroidX y no se por qué.

Comment: revisa las dependencias ya no debes tener nada que indique usar las bibliotecas de soporte

Comment: Voy a subir en foto las dependencias que tengo. Pero igualmente no tengo nada de support que yo sepa.